# No icon at Chrome's "Add to homes screen" using create-react-app

Tags: android, google-chrome, create-react-app

**manifest.json:**

```
...
"icons": [
  {
    "src": "icon.png",
    "sizes": "42x42",
    "type": "image/png"
  }
],
...
```

**index.html:**

```
...
<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/icon.png">
...
```

The icons appears, but when I use the "Add to home screen" feature for Chrome on Android I can't get it.

What can be done?